# Weblogic SAML 1.1 SSO with artifact cert missing

Tags: ssl, weblogic, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to setup a test environment for SSO with two domains on a server running Weblogic 10.2.  I was able to successfully utilize a login on a sample servlet on the SAML Source domain and connect with a link to a servlet on the SAML Destination domain.  This was using SAML 1.1 with Browser/POST relying party, as this was the sample provided with two domains on the Oracle documentation, utilizing a dummy appA and appB.  (I don't have the link handy to the sample instructions, but it worked well)

However my goal was to test SAML 1.1 with Browser/artifact scenario.  So I used the same security realms and setup a new AP for the Destination domain, and a new RP for the Source domain (keep in mind these are both running on the same machine).  I used the same SSL info and keystores/truststores/aliases (actually they are all using the same self-signed certs with alias "localhost"). And  It fails with a 403 error on the destination app.  I can see the artifact generated in the string:

```
https://localhost:7012/samlacs/acs?APID=ap_00002&SAMLart=AAH9R8ftHOp8ZwdBGik0ijXWFCYQZuUL%2FwTHd8JU%2Fo3aOkNGzkqbtuBm&TARGET=http://localhost:7010/appB/admin/services.jsp
```

But there is an error in the assertion lookup (or just before it in the artifact dereferencing):
(The artifacts do not match the log because I ran it again)
(Source domain):

```
Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLSourceSite: lookupStoredAssertions:         fetching assertion for artifact 'AAH9R8ftHOp8ZwdBGik0ijXWFCYQZoF3demE97Ls8pVqYxvva+3Mka/9'> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySAMLService> <blah> <AdminServer>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS     Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLSourceSite: verifyDestinationSite: auth     failure for partner 'rp_00002', client cert required but not provided> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySAMLService> <blah> <AdminServer>       <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS   Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLSourceSite: lookupStoredASsertions: auth   failure: missing/invalid credentials for partner 'rp_00002'> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySAMLService> <blah> <AdminServer>        <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS    Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLSourceSite: dispatchAssertionRequest:   destination site auth failure, returning FORBIDDEN> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE]   ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <>    <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <HttpRequest@20065100 - /samlars/ars: Writing headers for   HttpRequest@20065100 - /samlars/ars> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 160> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE]  ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <>   <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <Response committed. request: 'HttpRequest@20065100 -  /samlars/ars' response: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl@ea013e[
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: : Wed, 07 Nov 2012 23:04:59 GMT
Content-Length: : 1216
Content-Type: : text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
]>
```

(Destination domain):

```
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySAMLService> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLDestinationSiteHelper: Exception while sending/receiving request/response: org.opensaml.SAMLException: SAMLSOAPBinding.send(): Error response from server: '403 Forbidden'> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySAMLService> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <SAMLDestinationSiteHelper: Unable to dereference artifact -- returning SC_FORBIDDEN> 
###<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <HttpRequest@6557952 - /samlacs/acs: Writing headers for HttpRequest@6557952 - /samlacs/acs> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <HttpRequest@6557952 - /samlacs/acs: Wrote cookie: JSESSIONID=bkLSQhphfgFQGRnZNprd2kHJ71GGyPjsF91TMsn4pKkTMgLxcxVr!-98623638; path=/; HttpOnly> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <7PSS2Q1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 250> 
####<Nov 7, 2012 5:04:59 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <blah> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <>   <1352329499359> <BEA-000000> <Response committed. request: 'HttpRequest@6557952 -  /samlacs/acs' response: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl@2c3cd3[
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: : Wed, 07 Nov 2012 23:04:58 GMT
Content-Length: : 1216
Content-Type: : text/html
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=bkLSQhphfgFQGRnZNprd2kHJ71GGyPjsF91TMsn4pKkTMgLxcxVr!-98623638;  path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
]>
```

I can't see anywhere else to attach this missing client-cert in the relying party or assertion party.   Does anyone know what may be the issue?